# Optimizer for an SVM-like Model

Tags: python, optimization, svm

I've been studying the paper, "Support Vector Data Description". The authors describe a model similar to One-Class SVMs. However, the solution finds a sphere that encapsulates the samples. The objective function is formulated as:

[image]

K denotes the kernel function, and alpha is the adjustable parameter. I was thinking of solving this problem using PyTorch `autograd`, but the package has no method for enforcing the constraint. I've also checked the [SciPy optimization package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) but I'm not really familiar with any of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that's just weight regularization. You can use the weight decay parameter in your optimizer to implement L2 regularization.

If you want custom weight regularization, you can implement that in your loss function.

Comment: I don't understand how this loss function relates to weight normalizatiln. \alpha_i are the learnable parameters, not normalization coefficients.

Comment: Weight regularization is adding a function of the magnitude of the weights to your loss